# passing parameter to build a dynamic string in excel

Tags: excel

My requirement is very simple but i am not finding it easy-
In excel, column A is having 'Table name' and column B is having 'Column name'
I want to write a query-

Select * from 'column A' where 'column B' is not null.

In excel I have 2578 lines so I dont want to write 2578 Select statements.
any expert help in Excel?

Comment: You can put a filter, remove Blanks grip from the filter dropdown, select all... If you Copy and paste, copy only the filtered cell. also it's good to change format for that cells.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt this is your answer, but may help towards what you want. Based on @user3514930's approach:

[image: SO23675812 example]

With data as in the top left corner, select the two columns and click on DATA > Sort & Filter - Filter. Click on the arrow in the `Column name` cell and on `(Blanks)` in the dropdown. You should then see the equivalent of what is in the lower range. This can be copied and pasted elsewhere in the sheet, if you wish.